# How do you use the django-filter package with a list of parameters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to filter my model with [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter). It works fine if I filter by one id like:

```
http://localhost:8000/accommodations?accommodationType_id=1
```

But I don't know how I can filter by multiple ids like.

```
http://localhost:8000/accommodations?accommodationType_id=1,2
```

My actual `ViewSet` looks like this:

```
class AccommodationViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
        REST API endpoint for 'accommodation' resource
    """
    queryset = Accommodation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccommodationSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('accommodationType_id', 'name')
```

I hope there is a solution.

Comment: Did you tried: `http://localhost:8000/accommodations?accommodationType_id=1&accommodationType_id=2`

Comment: Yes, an I get the last object with accommodationType_id=2

Comment: In my testing passing multiple of the same parameter gives all results where all of the values match, i.e. `AND`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the following solution for my problem :)

https://gist.github.com/aBuder/654fb945f085b17358d8

```
from webapp.serializers import *
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters
from django_filters import Filter, FilterSet


class ListFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if not value:
            return qs

        # For django-filter versions < 0.13, use lookup_type instead of lookup_expr
        self.lookup_expr = 'in'
        values = value.split(',')
        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(qs, values)


class AccommodationFilter(FilterSet):
    ids = ListFilter(name='id')
    accommodationType_ids = ListFilter(name='accommodationType_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Accommodation
        fields = ['ids', 'accommodationType_ids']


class AccommodationViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
        REST API endpoint for 'accommodation' resource
    """
    queryset = Accommodation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccommodationSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = AccommodationFilter
```

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me a lot.  If you have any other tips now that you've been working on it, I will really appreciate it!  I need to get items based on a list often

Answer (score 22):

I know it is an old question, but might be worth it to give an updated answer.

Django-filter contributors have added a field called `BaseInFilter` which you can combine with other filters to validate the content.

See the docs:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter

For example, this would work in your case:

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class NumberInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.NumberFilter):
    pass


class AccommodationFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    accommodationType_id_in = NumberInFilter(field_name='accommodationType_id', lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Accommodation
        fields = ['accommodationType_id_in', ]
```

Then you would be able to filter by a list of ids: `http://localhost:8000/accommodations?accommodationType_id_in=1,2`

Comment: Very useful, awesome

Comment: Or even easier, django-filter takes "fields" as a dictionary, where you can specify lookups. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields
Found it first in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020090/filter-on-multiple-values-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 6):

Now there is an even simpler way to achieve this. Deep within the [`django-filter` documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields), it mentions that you can use "a dictionary of field names mapped to a list of lookups".

Your code would be updated like so:

```
class AccommodationViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
        REST API endpoint for 'accommodation' resource
    """
    queryset = Accommodation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccommodationSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = {
        'accommodationType_id': ["in", "exact"], # note the 'in' field
        'name': ["exact"]
    }
```

Now in the URL you would add `__in` to the filter before supplying your list of parameters and it would work as you expect:

```
http://localhost:8000/accommodations?accommodationType_id__in=1,2
```

The `django-filter` documentation on what lookup filters are available is quite poor, but the `in` lookup filter is mentioned in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) itself.

Comment: How to customize the field name in url params? i.e. i don't want to use the `__in` postfix in url

Comment: I don't know of a way to get around using `__in` unfortunately.