# Filter with multiple values in get request with django-filters using a MethodFilter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to create a FilterSet with filters set with a MethodFilter expecting multiple values like that :

#### Filters.py

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    first_filter = django_filters.MethodFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = ['first_filter']

    def filter_first_filter(self, queryset, value):
        # I expect value to setup with an array of values
        myquery = Q()
        return queryset.filter(myquery)
```

#### Views.py

```
class MyView(RetrieveAPIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        filter = MyFilter(request.query_params, queryset=myModel.objects.all())
        # Other things go there using the filter instanciated
```

So when I request the view with this kind of URL /my_view?first_filter=thing1&first_filter=thing2, Only thing2 is passed in the value of the method filter_first_filter instead of ['thing1', 'thing2].

How to change this behaviour ?

Comment: Try to debug like I did with **pdb** package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the django-filter package with a list of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/how-do-you-use-the-django-filter-package-with-a-list-of-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out why that was not working.

The fact to instanciate the FilterSet with request.query_params was wrong because query_params is a QueryDict and the get function of the QueryDict returns only the last element. So to solve the problem, I should do :

```
class MyView(RetrieveAPIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        dict_params = dict(request.query_params.iterlists())
        filter = MyFilter(dict_params, queryset=myModel.objects.all())
```