# Django REST filter backend for query list

Tags: python, django, rest

I have a model called Job and serialize the jobs to /-/jobs/ using the Django REST framework.
The DjangoBackendFilter allows me to filter my jobs like this

> http://192.168.99.100:8000/-/jobs/?owner=1

which gives me all jobs of owner 1.

What I need, however, is a way to filter for a list of owners maybe like this

> http://192.168.99.100:8000/-/jobs/?owner=1,4,77

That would give me the jobs with the owners 1, 4, and 77.

I thought about using *get_queryset()* for that, but I am looking for a more general solution, because I have several API endpoints and would like to use filter function in each of the endpoint without specifying get_queryset() each time.

Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to extend the DjangoBackendFilter by defining how to handle a list of values in a query!?

Or is there another package that solves the Problem? I found [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters)
, which seems to extend DjangoBackendFilter in many ways but does not support a list of values in a query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31086033/3794660 ? Looks similar to your case.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That solves my problem.