# How to filter against multiple values for ForeignKey using DjangoFilterBackend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have model with following fields:

- loading_port
- discharge_port
- carrier
- supplier

All these fields are ForeignKey to models that contains `name` field.

Also I have viewset, which uses DjangoFilter backend for filtering. At this moment I want to make possible filtering multiple values for each field, like:

`loading_port__name=PORT_1&loading_port__name=PORT_2&supplier__name=SUPP_NAME_1&supplier__name=SUPP_NAME_2` and so on. However if I actually pass this url it returns rows that filters against last parameter value (in this example for loading_port - PORT_2, for supplier - SUPP_NAME_2).

How can I fix filtering so it will meet my requirements?

Comment: Hi! can you provide code for models and view where do you use those filters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the django-filter package with a list of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/how-do-you-use-the-django-filter-package-with-a-list-of-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However if I actually pass this url it returns rows that filters against last parameter value

This is because `ForeignKey` fields default to `ModelChoiceFilter`, which just takes a single value from the `GET` `QueryDict`.

If you declare your fields as `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` they will take the list of values you require.