# Django-filters: multiple IDs in a single query string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Using [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I see various solutions for how to submit multiple arguments of the same type in a single query string, for example for multiple IDs. They all suggest using a separate field that contains a comma-separated list of values, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/api/cities?ids=1,2,3
```

Is there a general solution for using a single parameter but submitted one or more times? E.g.:

```
http://example.com/api/cities?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

I tried using [`MultipleChoiceFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#multiplechoicefilter), but it expects actual choices to be defined whereas I want to pass arbitrary IDs (some of which may not even exist in the DB).

Comment: What do you mean with *some not even exist in the db*? What should happen then?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem A standard IN lookup should be used. If you request `id=1&id=2` and resource with ID 2 does not exist, only the first one would be returned in the list of results. If neither exist, an empty list would be returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the django-filter package with a list of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/how-do-you-use-the-django-filter-package-with-a-list-of-parameters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a **reusable solution** using a custom `Filter` and a custom [`Field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field).

The custom `Field` reuses Django's [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) but replaces the validation functions.
Instead, it validates using another `Field` class that we pass to the constructor.

```py
from django.forms.fields import MultipleChoiceField

class MultipleValueField(MultipleChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, field_class, **kwargs):
        self.inner_field = field_class()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def valid_value(self, value):
        return self.inner_field.validate(value)

    def clean(self, values):
        return values and [self.inner_field.clean(value) for value in values]
```

The custom `Filter` uses `MultipleValueField` and forwards the `field_class` argument.
It also sets the default value of `lookup_expr` to `in`.

```py
from django_filters.filters import Filter

class MultipleValueFilter(Filter):
    field_class = MultipleValueField

    def __init__(self, *args, field_class, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('lookup_expr', 'in')
        super().__init__(*args, field_class=field_class, **kwargs)
```

To use this filter, simply create a `MultipleValueFilter` with the appropriate `field_class`. For example, to filter `City` by `id`, we can use a [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield), like so:

```py
from django.forms.fields import IntegerField

class CityFilterSet(FilterSet):
    id = MultipleValueFilter(field_class=IntegerField)
    name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name']
```

Comment: thanks for this. I've posted an improvement to allow for lookup_exprs such as iexact. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162262/1321009

Answer (score 7):

As option

```py
class CityFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.NumberFilter(method='filter_id')

    def filter_id(self, qs, name, value):
        return qs.filter(id__in=self.request.GET.getlist('id'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved using a custom filter, inspired by Jerin's answer:

```
class ListFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, queryset, value):
        try:
            request = self.parent.request
        except AttributeError:
            return None

        values = request.GET.getlist(self.name)
        values = {int(item) for item in values if item.isdigit()}

        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(queryset, Lookup(values, 'in'))
```

If the values were to be non-digit, e.g. `color=blue&color=red` then the `isdigit()` validation is of course not necessary.

Comment: Seems weird to me that this is not default behavior in django-filters yet... It is a common use case.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use a custom filter, as below

```
from django_filters.filters import Filter
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
from django_filters.fields import Lookup


class ListFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, queryset, value):
        list_values = value.split(',')
        if not all(item.isdigit() for item in list_values):
            raise ValidationError('All values in %s the are not integer' % str(list_values))
        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(queryset, Lookup(list_values, 'in'))
```

Comment: Right, that's the solution for when you want to pass multiple values as `ids=1,2,3`, but I'm specifically looking for how to handle multiple arguments of the same name, so `id=1&id=2&id=3`.

Answer (score 2):

I have some problems with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799411/django-filters-multiple-ids-in-a-single-query-string/50810840#50810840)

So I changed it a bit:

```py
class ListFilter(Filter):
    def __init__(self, query_param, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # url = /api/cities/?id=1&id=2&id=3 or /api/cities/?id=1,2,3
        # or /api/cities/?id=1&id=2&id=3?id=4,5,6
        self.query_param = query_param 
        self.lookup_expr = 'in'

    def filter(self, queryset, value):
        try:
            request = self.parent.request
        except AttributeError:
            return None

        values = set()
        query_list = request.GET.getlist(self.query_param)
        for v in query_list:
            values = values.union(set(v.split(',')))
        values = set(map(int, values))

        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(queryset, values)
```

```py
class CityFilter(filterset.FilterSet):
    id = ListFilter(field_name='id', query_param='id')
    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name']
```

If you want to use custom query param name - change `query_param` arg.

Answer (score 2):

On `django-filter` version 22.1 we can use `django_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter()`.

```py
import django_filters


class CityFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter(label='id')
```

On browsable API it can show the current `id` options it can use as values.
[image]

Comment: Love it when there's a native way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

[Benoit Blanchon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164966/benoit-blanchon) had imo the best

But I've tried to improve on it to allow for more types of lookup_expr's.
See his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64551934/1321009) for the complete code snippets.

```
from django.db.models import Q

class MultipleValueFilter(Filter):
    field_class = MultipleValueField

    def __init__(self, *args, field_class, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('lookup_expr', 'in')
        super().__init__(*args, field_class=field_class, **kwargs)

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        # if it's not a list then let the parent deal with it
        if self.lookup_expr == 'in' or not isinstance(value, list):
            return super().filter(qs, value)

        # empty list
        if not value:
            return qs
        if self.distinct:
            qs = qs.distinct()

        lookup = '%s__%s' % (self.field_name, self.lookup_expr)
        filters = Q()
        for v in value:
            filters |= Q(**{lookup: v})
        qs = self.get_method(qs)(filters)
        return qs
```

With this change you can now use iexact for example.
You can also use gte, etc, but those will probably not make much sense.

Answer (score -3):

http://example.com/api/cities?ids=1,2,3

```
get_ids=1,2,3
id_list = list(get_ides]
Mdele_name.objects.filter(id__in= id_list)
```