# How to filter a comma separated string in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have some data that is similar to this:

`position: "1B, 2B, 3B, SS"`

I'd like to be able to run a query such as `/players/?position=1B`, however, this currently does not return anything because the items are separated by a comma.

Here is stripped down version of the views.py:

```
class CharInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.CharFilter):
    pass

class PlayerProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    position = CharInFilter(field_name='display_position', lookup_expr='in')
```

Is there a way to filter the data in this way?

Comment: Try `lookup_expr='contains'`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains

Comment: @IainShelvington: but will that not work the other way around? This thus means that the position should contain `1B, 2B, 3B, SS`. But likely this is a simple `CharField`, so the contains would only work if the `position` of the player is something like `...1B, 2B, 3B, SS...`

Comment: @IainShelvington you are correct. Thats the exact behavior when using contsins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a [custom filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method).

```
from django.db.models import Q

import django_filters


class PlayerProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    position = django_filters.CharFilter(method="my_custom_filter")

    def my_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        query = Q()
        for position in value.split(","):
            query |= Q(position__contains=position)
        return queryset.filter(query)
```

Comment: That got me closer but now I'm guessing the following error: `'QuerySet' object is not callable`

Comment: @JeremyE just a reminder: if the answer help you, please upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a custom filter class.

You can use something from [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering)

```
from rest_framework import filters

class MyFilter(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        # logic here
        return queryset
```

Or filter [django-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810402/13022138)

```
from django_filters.filters import Filter

class MyFilter(Filter):
    def filterself, request, queryset, view):
        # logic here
        return queryset
```