# Django REST Framework filter backend with multiple value?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I want to get query list with one key more values. For example,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/device/model/list/?device_type=1&hardware_model_mother=master&hardware_model_mother=MasterModel1&hardware_model_child=SlaveModel1
```

Then i can get query list of `device_type=1,hardware_model_child=SlaveModel1,hardware_model_mother=master`
and `device_type=1,hardware_model_child=SlaveModel1,hardware_model_mother=MasterModel1`.
I need a list of fields that's why i didn't use the function `in_bulk()`.

I found some filters in django-filter's doc, here's the link:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html

I choose `MultipleChoiceFilter`, it will use OR, that's what i wanted.

Here's my filter's code:

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, MultipleChoiceFilter
from Device_set.views.DeviceModelFilter import DeviceModelFilter
from .head import *


# one key for multiple values
class DeviceModelFilter(FilterSet):
    MOTHER_CHOICES, CHILD_CHOICES = DeviceModelFilter().MyChoices()
    hardware_model_mother = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=MOTHER_CHOICES)
    hardware_model_child = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=CHILD_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = device_model
        fields = ['hardware_model_mother', 'hardware_model_child']
```

and my ListAPIView:

```
class DeviceModelListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [Developer | IOTWatch | IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = DeviceModelListSerializer
    queryset = device_model.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = DeviceModelFilter
    search_fields = ('id', 'name')
    filterset_fields = ('hardware_model_mother', 'hardware_model_child')

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        dtype = self.request.query_params.get('device_type')
        if dtype is not None:
            queryset = self.queryset.filter(device_type__icontains=dtype)
        else:
            queryset = self.queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(Return_msg(self.list(request)))
```

when url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/device/model/list/?device_type=1&hardware_model_mother=master&hardware_model_mother=MasterModel1`

The result is right:
[right response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbjQ9.png)

However, when url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/device/model/list/?device_type=1&hardware_model_child=SlaveModel1`

It's wrong:
[false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvgrq.png)

Traceback:
[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krP8p.png)

It cost me about one day to solve this problem, could you please tell me how to fix it, or anther way to implement it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the django-filter package with a list of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/how-do-you-use-the-django-filter-package-with-a-list-of-parameters)