# Filter for Multiple values of a field in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

In Amazon you can filter by Multiple Brands, eg. You select Nike, Puma, Adidas. The queryset that is sent back has products which belong to either of those brands.

if you have a model like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

a serializer like:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

viewset like:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [filters.ProductMultipleFilterBackend ]
```

filters.py file:

```
from rest_framework import filters as drf_filters
from django_filters import rest_framework as df_filters

class MultipleField(MultipleChoiceField):
    def valid_value(self, value):   
        return True

class MultipleFilter(df_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter):
    field_class = MultipleField

class ProductMultipleFilterBackend(df_filters.FilterSet):
    brand = MultipleFilter(lookup_expr="icontains", field_name = "brand")
    search = MultipleFilter(lookup_expr="icontains", field_name = "description")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = ["brand", "search"]
```

the above code was something i found [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/137#issuecomment-37820702). But it's like 5 years old and there might be a better way that i surely don't know about and  i'm getting the following error on the code:

```
filter_queryset() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

What would be the url structure for these requests:
/someurl?brand=Nike,Adidas,Puma
or
/someurl?brand=[Nike,Adidas,Puma]

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DjangoFilterBackend with multiple ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/djangofilterbackend-with-multiple-ids)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal behavior for `multiple choice` is like `?f=v1&f=v2`, while you could pass proper `widget` to change the default url structure to comma separated value by using `CSVWidget`

```
from django_filters.fields import CSVWidget

class ProductMultipleFilterBackend(df_filters.FilterSet):
    brand = MultipleFilter(
                 lookup_expr="icontains", 
                 field_name = "brand",
                 widget=CSVWidget
            )
     ...
```

Then, you could filter using csv format like: `url?brand=a,b`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply by setting out the django-filter and adding lookup fields in the view

```
class VendorFlashListAPI(generics.ListAPIView): #to get flashes with location
model = Flash
serializer_class = VendorFlashSerializer

#adding the backends so that i can find
filter_backends[DjangoFilterBackend]

----------FOCUS HERE ------------

filterset_fields = {
    # note the 'in' field
    'district': ["in","exact"],
    'state  ': ["in","exact"], 
      #with adding "in" i can search like ?district__in=1,2
      #with adding "exact" i can search like ?district=1
}
```

You can read the full article [here](https://medium.com/@muhammadshamshad365/django-rest-framework-django-filter-same-parameter-multiple-value-search-7809e63dc55a)