# Django Rest Framework - Filter multiple values on the same field (OR)

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using Django Rest Framework along with the `django-filter` package and I have the following example model:

```
class EgModel(models.Model):
    eg_foreing_key = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, ...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

I also have the following viewset:

```
class EgModelViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = EgModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EgModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    search_fields = ['name']
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I request to `/egs/?search=anything&eg_foreign_key=1&eg_foreign_key=2` I get the results that match the search (working fine) and also have that reference to eg_foreign_key that has id 1 or 2 in this example.

I tried using `DjangoFilterBackend` and `filterset_fields` for `ef_foreign_key` and it works but just for a single value (the last one). I could probably workaround using `def get_queryset()` but if possible I would like to use `django-filter` for it.

Comment: You want the drf filters extension and the `AllLookupsFilter`: https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-filters/0.3.1/

Comment: @wim I just installed it but I'm getting a ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils', have you come across it already?

Comment: @wim Also, if it's not asking too much, could you show me some code using it for my case? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DjangoFilterBackend with multiple ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/djangofilterbackend-with-multiple-ids)