# Filter on multiple values in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, filtering, django-rest-viewsets

I have a model that I want to filter on multiple values.

my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ean = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    product_image = models.URLField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

I either want to filter on the 'ean' field, or on the primary key, both will work. With my current set up, I only see the last value. For example, when I construct the URL as [www.example.com/api/Product/?id=1&id=2](http://www.example.com/api/Product/?id=1&id=2), I only get see the product with id 2, and I want to see product with id 1 and with id 2.

How should I construct my ViewSet?
Currently I have:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields  = ('id','ean')
```

Comment: Use [filterset class](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class) which will give you more control over filtering operations

Comment: Could you maybe give an example @ArakkalAbu?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is an even simpler way to achieve this using the [`django-filter` package](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Deep within the [`django-filter` documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields), it mentions that you can use "a dictionary of field names mapped to a list of lookups".

Your code would be updated like so:

```
# views.py

from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {
        'id': ["in", "exact"], # note the 'in' field
        'ean': ["exact"]
    }
```

Now in the URL you would add `__in` to the filter before supplying your list of parameters and it would work as you expect:

```
www.example.com/api/Product/?id__in=1,2
```

The `django-filter` documentation on what lookup filters are available is quite poor, but the `in` lookup filter is mentioned in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) itself.

Comment: `filterset_fields` instead of filter_fields worked for me

Comment: hard to find this in the documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in your `views.py` and pass your keys `id` and `ean` in params. Notice that you have to pass the multiple values as comma separated values in params.

```
class ProductViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        _id   = self.request.GET.get('id', None).split(',')
        ean   = self.request.GET.get('ean', None).split(',')

        qs = Product.objects.filter(Q(id__in=_id) | Q(ean__in=ean))
        data = serializers.ProductSerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request': request}).data

        if data:
                return Response({
                        'message': 'success',
                        "data":data,
                    },status=200)
            else:
                return Response({
                        'message':'no data available',
                        'success':'False'
                    },status=200)
```