# DRF filtering with `fieldset_filters` using multiple queries for the same queryparam

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, query-string

I'm using `Django` and `DRF`, with `DjangoFilterBackend` for filtering the queryset results.

How do you pass multiple queries to the same queryparam?

For example if I had 'id' set in `filterset_fields=['id']`, to enable filtering Users by their ID.

To filter for id 99, the `url` would look like this: `api/user/?id=99`.

How would you filter for multiple ID's in one request? Is it even possible?

I would like to be able to do something like this:  `api/user/?id=99,133,234` or maybe  `api/user/?id=99&id=133&id=234`.

This is currently NOT working for me, it just returns the last param.

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a previous answer that can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/djangofilterbackend-with-multiple-ids)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DjangoFilterBackend with multiple ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029792/djangofilterbackend-with-multiple-ids)

Comment: Nope. I got an error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`.
Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not obvious, but there is a way. You will need to use `filter_class = YourFilterSet` instead of `filterset_fields`. The query will be `?id=99,133,234`

```
from django_filters import BaseInFilter
from django_filters import NumberFilter

class NumberInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class YourFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = NumberInFilter(field_name='id')
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Alexandr Tatarinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6627564/alexandr-tatarinov) !!

I might add that NumberInFilter is a made up name, you can call it whatever you'd like.
Also to get the same functionality for strings, you would just create another filter class and inherit the Django-Filter called CharFilter like so:

```
from django_filters import BaseInFilter, NumberFilter, CharFilter

class NumberInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):    
    pass

class CountryInFilter(BaseInFilter, CharFilter):    
    pass

class YourFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):  
    id = NumberInFilter(field_name='id')  
    country = CountryInFilter(field_name='country')
```

now you can call the api like this and it works!
api/?id=12,33,543
OR
api/?country=usa,panama,india