# Build request URL to filter Django queryset multiple times by the same field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-q

I want to filter Django queryset by the same field multiple times using `Q` to include/exclude records with specific value in this field.

I'll use sample model to illustrate my case. Say I have a `Record` model with field `status`. This field can be one of three states `A`, `B`, `C`.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    STATUS_A = 'A'
    STATUS_B = 'B'
    STATUS_C = 'C'

    SOME_STATUSES = (
        (STATUS_A, 'Something A'),
        (STATUS_B, 'Something B'),
        (STATUS_C, 'Something C'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices= SOME_STATUSES,
    default= STATUS_A,
    )
```

I have a [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) `ViewSet` that's responsible for returning filtered queryset of `Record` objects.

Right now I'm filtering query set by a single status, so my `URL` looks something like:

```
.../?status=A
.../?status=B
.../?status=C
```

But say I want to filter queryset by multiple statuses:
Return all records with status `A` and `B`.
Or instead I want to return all the records except those with status `C`. I'm not sure how to build URL in those cases. I know that duplicating parameters in URL is a very bad practice:

```
.../?status=A&status=B
```

How does one request `A` `AND` `B` or `NOT` `C`?

The remaining part of the question how to handle those multiple values is unclear probably because I don't understand how to build such a query in the first place.

Comment: Can you share the `ViewSet` code? DRF has some support for membership checks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's rather vast, because the actual ViewSet filters a query with several different params and I'm using several Mixins to keep things in order. I'll try to minimise it to fit a question and upload it later today. But mainly my question is how to build such url's.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18016543/67579

Comment: I think you should send an `array` on the querystring and then filter in the backend. `.../?status=[A,B,C]`. Also try to use `django-filters`

Comment: `/?status_must=A,B&status_mustnot=C` Is this your expected url?

Comment: @JPG this looks interesting, but a bit hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing CustomDjangoFilter you can achieve this.

**Sample Code**

*URL examples and Usage*

```
URL  : localhost:8000/records/?status_include=A,B
URL  : localhost:8000/records/?status_exclude=A
URL  : localhost:8000/records/?status_include=A,B,C&status_exclude=D,E,F
```

*Code Snippet*

views.py

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .filters import CustomRecordFilter

class RecordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer

    # django-filter-backend and custom-filter-class
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_class = CustomRecordFilter
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters

class CustomRecordFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    status_exclude = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='status', method='filter_status_exclude')
    status_include = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='status', method='filter_status_include')

def filter_status_include(self, queryset, name, value):
    if not value:
        return queryset
    values = ''.join(value.split(' ')).split(',')
    queryset = queryset.filter(status__in=values)
    return queryset

def filter_status_exclude(self, queryset, name, value):
    if not value:
        return queryset
    values = ''.join(value.split(' ')).split(',')

    # exclude status
    queryset = queryset.exclude(status__in=values)
    return queryset

class Meta:
    model = UserRoleGroup
    fields = ('status', 'status_include', 'status_exclude')
```