# Django-filter __in lookup

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    label = django_filters.LookupChoiceFilter(
        lookup_choices=[
            ('contains', 'Contains'),
            ('in', 'In')
        ]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['label']

class ListProduct(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

"http://localhost:8000/api?label=foo&label_lookup=contains"
works fine but 
"http://localhost:8000/api?label=foo,bar&label_lookup=in"
returns an empty list.**I want this to return all records containing 'foo' or 'bar'.**

I tried different approaches but couldn't make it work. Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-filter '\_\_in' lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016543/django-filter-in-lookup)

Comment: @xyres Similar but not a duplicate. In my case, it's a list of strings not numbers. Also, I want to keep other lookup options like 'contains'. I have checked these posts before posting. They are not working for me.