# How do you filter one field using multiple values in ListAPIView in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do you filter one field using multiple values in `ListAPIView` in Django REST framework?

**URL:** `/api/items/?status=active&status=pending`

I need to get results that have either "active" or pending "status". What `filter_backends` will be good for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`django-filter` package](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s DjangoFilterBackend for that:

```
from django_filters import DjangoFilterBackend

class profile_view(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ModelName.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SerializerName
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = {
        'status': ["in", "exact"] # icontains ,exact, gte, lte, in
         # if you want to add more fields, you can
    }
```

then you can filter data by `?status__in=active, pending` or `status=active`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DjangoDefaultFilterBackend like that:

```
from django_filters import DjangoFilterBackend
class YourListAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['status']
```

You can find more detail abouth [drf-filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering)

If you want to use filter multiple values for same field , there is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56025770/7659834)

Comment: This won't let you filter by multiple values, only by single values.