# Django-Filters Lookup_expr type 'AND'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

Does Django-Filters have a lookup_expr equivalent to 'AND'?

I am using Django filters with DRF to filter by multiple categories on the same field.

Example:
I have a category list field that accepts multiple categories

categories = ['baking', 'cooking', 'desserts', 'etc']

Using the solution outlined by udeep below I got the filter to work rather well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322368/13142864

The one issue I am running into is with the lookup_expr="in"

This works as an 'OR' expression.

So if I provide a filter query of 
categories=baking,cooking

It will return all results that contain either 'baking' OR 'cooking'

Is there a lookup_expr in django_filters that profiles an 'AND' functionality so that when I make the same query I get only results that contain both 'baking' AND 'cooking'?

I have looked at all of the django filter docs
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/

And all of the django queryset filter where many of these type of filters seem to originate from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

But unfortunately, I have had no luck. Any direction you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the URL  `/end-point/?categories=baking&categories=cooking` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu thanks for the recommendation. I tried it, but unfortunately, that returns an OR response query as well. If you have any other recommendations I would be much appreciated.