# How to create MultipleChoiceField in django-filter?

Tags: python, django, django-filter, multiple-choice

I have a model Color:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
```

And my Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=CASCADE)
    ...
```

So i need to create a filter that i'll able to get for example all red, blue or yellow products

**How can i do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a filter with multiple choices for a model you can use the [`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` [django-filter docs]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#modelmultiplechoicefilter). You can also pass the form `widget` you want to get used for the field, hence for checkboxes you would pass [`CheckboxSelectMultiple` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple):

```py
from django import forms
import django_filters


class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    color = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Color.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['color']  # Add any other fields you want to filter to the list
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @Ihor uhh, you are not supposed to literally write `...` there, you need to replace those with other fields you might want to filter.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot about it

Comment: Can i change it to checkboxes instead of list?

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Product.objects.filter(color__name=some_color_name)
```

with *`some_color_name`* for example 'Yellow'. If you have a color object, you can work with:

```
Product.objects.filter(color=some_color)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations.

Comment: But what if i have a django-filter form?And i need not only one color. I need several
For example i have 20 colors in my database and user wants to get the product with his favorite colors

Comment: @ihor: you can then filter with `Product.objects.filter(color__name__in=['Red', 'Blue'])`

Comment: @ihor: as for django-filter, you can speciy an `__in` lookup as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59988897/67579

Comment: i mean how to add a field with this filter if django-filter needs built-in django-filter filters?

Comment: @ihor: you add `in` to the `filter_fields = {'color__name': ['in']}`, and thus pass it in the query with `?color__name__in=red,blue`.

Comment: moreover idk what color user will choose thus i need to create many checkboxes for each of color

Comment: @ihor: you can do that by specifying the widget to a `CheckboxSelectMultiple`,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234983/discussion-between-ihor-and-willem-van-onsem).